# C# Регистро чувствительный JsonProperty

Tags: c#, newtonsoft.json

У меня от сервера приходит следующая структура:

```
{
    "a": 2612272441,
    "p": "27556.67000000",
    "q": "0.00173000",
    "f": 3091609090,
    "l": 3091609090,
    "T": 1682261520001,
    "m": false,
    "M": true
}
```

В ней возвращается 2 поля (m и M) - отличие лишь в регистре.

Мне нужно десериализовать этот json в следующий объект:

```
public readonly record struct AggregatedTradeInfoResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public ulong Id { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// First tradeId.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("f")]
    public ulong FirstId { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Last tradeId.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("l")]
    public ulong LastId { get; init; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Цена.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("p")]
    public decimal Price { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("q")]
    public decimal Qty { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Время сделки.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("T")]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Является ли покупатель создателем.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("m")]
    public bool IsBuyerMaker { get; init; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Является лучшим совпадением.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("M")]
    public bool IsBestMatch { get; init; }
}
```

Однако при десиарелизации (используется Newtonsoft) возникает ошибка так как библиотека считает M и m одинаковыми параметрами. КАк с помощью аттрибутов сказать что требуется CaseSensitive вусуриализация?

Текст ошибки :
A member with the name 'm' already exists on 'AT.Connectors.Binance.Models.Spot.MarketData.AggregatedTradeInfoResponse'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

Настройки Json сериализатора:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters =
            {
                new StringEnumConverter(new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()),
                new StringEnumConverter(new KebabCaseNamingStrategy()),
                new StringEnumConverter(),
                new DateTimeOffsetConverter()
            },
        };
```

Comment: Ошибку покажите, которую вам дает десериализатор, ух что-то я сомневаюсь, что там ругается на это...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ A member with the name 'm' already exists on 'AT.Connectors.Binance.Models.Spot.MarketData.AggregatedTradeInfoResponse'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

Comment: почему ты в одном случае используешь `[JsonProperty("m")]` а в другом `[JsonPropertyName("M")]`?

Comment: @Grundy - Посмотри Json который ко мне приходит (в вопросе первым идет) - 2 последних поля

Comment: Ок, тогда код десериализации показывайте, ибо почему у меня тогда [все работает](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2b5Iea)? (поменял только тип даты, и сделал всем "м" `true`)

Comment: @ т.е. заглавную букву ?
Десериализует библиотека RestEasy (https://github.com/canton7/RestEase) - под капотом там встрое NewtonSoft Json serialiser.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - Кчли обе заглавные - то смысла нет - как тогда понять в какое поле какое из значений сериализовать ?

Comment: Где вы увидели обе заглавные? Я чисто скопировал ваш JSON, взял голый Newtonsoft.Json, взял вашу структуру в которой поменял лишь тип даты (ибо по умолчанию дата не десериализуется из числа), поправил "очепятку" в атрибутах, и сделал десериализацию, как видите, код успешно отработал, забрал и большую, и малую буквы, занес из них данные в нужные свойства. Так что, это проблема не в десериализаторе, а в вашем коде, ваших настройках десериализатора, которые нам вы не показали.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Какую именно очебятку Вы поправили ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ настройки сейчас приложу

Comment: Вам выше про нее сказали, вы используете `JsonProperty` (атрибут Newtonsoft.Json) и `JsonPropertyName` (атрибут встроенного сериализатора System.Text.Json). Вообще код я вам показал, изучайте, смотрите, анализируйте, сравнивайте со своим, смотрите что у вас лишнего такого, что мешает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - Нес я всюду использую JsonProperty. Скопировал вариант когда игрался с настройками. Тут промах верно.

Comment: `ContractResolver` уберите из настроек, и будет вам счастье)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да получилось, благодарю.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar `JsonProperty` и `JsonPropertyName`